# Why doesn't Python statsmodels...SARIMAX.predict work?

Tags: time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to use `SARIMAX` to extend a 34-element monthly time series to 35 elements, assuming a 12-month seasonal component.

However, the `predict` method fails with the traceback:

```
<ipython-input-40-151295bf5e3e> in approach_4_stationarity(data_file_name)
     27     sarima = SARIMAX( total_items_array, order = ( 1, 0, 0 ), seasonal_order = (0,0,0,12) )
     28     sarima.fit()
---> 29     next_month_item_cnt = sarima.predict( (1, 0, 0 ), start = 34, end = 34 )
     30     print( "next_month_item_cnt", next_month_item_cnt, file = sys.stderr )
     31     total_items_array = total_items_array.append( next_month_item_cnt )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in predict(self, params, exog, *args, **kwargs)
    205         This is a placeholder intended to be overwritten by individual models.
    206         """
--> 207         raise NotImplementedError
    208 
    209
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fit` method does not affect the model object, it returns a new results object. You probably want something like the following:

```
model = SARIMAX(total_items_array, order=(1, 0, 0), seasonal_order=(0,0,0,12))
results = model.fit()
next_month_item_cnt = results.forecast(steps=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells the method is not implemented and I personally never seen anything like this. Be shure to check documentation or FAQ section on the [official website](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html).

There is a solution. You can use the `auto_arima` function from `pmdarima`. It's fully automatic in identifying the parameters of SARIMA model, but (from my experience) it's time consuming and not effective at 100%. I would suggest you to see all its parameters and then you can use it like this:

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima

step_wise=auto_arima(train_y, exogenous= train_X, start_p=1, start_q=1, 
     max_p=7, max_q=7, d=1, max_d=7, trace=True, error_action=’ignore’, 
     suppress_warnings=True, stepwise=True)
```

Code taken from [this article.](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/time-series-prediction-using-sarimax-a6604f258c56)
.
Check official docs about `auto_arima` [here](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html?highlight=auto#pmdarima.arima.auto_arima)